# Loop through single array and multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just starting out in JavaScript and looking to iterate over an array and then match that to the value of the volume of rows in the 2d array. This is what I've got so far:

```
const relatedKeywords = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3'];
const relatedURLs = 
[ [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ],
  [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ],
  [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ] ]

      for (let y = 0; y < relatedKeywords.length; y++) {

        for (let z = 0; z < relatedURLs[0].length; z++) {
          console.log(relatedURLs[z].length)
        }
      }
```

This returns the volume of URLs in the 2d array, but iterates 6 times. Ideally, I want to get to a point where the outputs looks like this:

```
Keyword1 = 2 URLs
Keyword2 = 2 URLs
Keyword3 = 2 URLs
```

Comment: You have two unrelated arrays that you are looping... Either loop only once, or come up with a way to relate / compare the arrays to only print when you need. I do not understand the ask here - why would you need to loop over they keywords, then get the related URLs without any additional processing? You inner and outer loop are completely unrelated here.

Comment: I am confused here why you have a second loop, is sounds like your goal is simply to `console.log(relatedURLs[y].length)` without the 2nd loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `forEach` with a template literal string like so:

```js
const relatedKeywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'];
const relatedURLs = [
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ]
];

relatedKeywords.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(`${item} = ${relatedURLs[index].length} URLs`);
});
```

ES5 syntax should you need it:

```js
const relatedKeywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'];
const relatedURLs = [
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ]
];

relatedKeywords.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(item + " = " + relatedURLs[index].length + " URLs");
});
```

With a `for` loop:

```js
const relatedKeywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3'];
const relatedURLs = [
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ],
  ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/'
  ]
];

for (var index = 0; index < relatedKeywords.length; index++) {
  let item = relatedKeywords[index];
  console.log(item + " = " + relatedURLs[index].length + " URLs");
}
```

Comment: This is great - thank you! Could you ever run 2 for loops in this case, or would you always run a forEach loop?

Comment: You can run two for loops, but it's much simpler to use a `forEach` loop.

Comment: Brilliant - out of interest, how would you use a for loop in this instance and where was I going wrong?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show how to use a for loop - basically, you were iterating over the inner loop too many times and not doing what you needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a array map and process it the way its required to

```js
const relatedKeywords = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3'];
const relatedURLs = 
[ [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ],
  [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ],
  [ 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee',
    'https://www.joscoffee.com/' ] ]

    
relatedKeywords.map(function(value,index) {
  console.log(value + ' = ' + relatedURLs[index].length + ' URLs');
});
```